# QPrintPreviewDialog 100% Zoom

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, zooming, qprinter

[image]

How do I set a 100% default value in QPrintPreviewDialog, Always a small page appears to me, I want to display it clearly automatically instead of choosing the number manually

Note. I did not find anything in this topic on this site

```
def handlePreview(self, InNum):
    self.printer = QPrinter()
    self.printer.setPageSize(QPrinter.A4)
    self.printer.setOrientation(QPrinter.Portrait)
    self.printer.setPageMargins(0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, QPrinter.Millimeter)

    dialog = QPrintPreviewDialog(self.printer)
    dialog.setWindowState(QtCore.Qt.WindowMaximized)
    dialog.paintRequested.connect(lambda: self.preparationHtml(InNum))
    dialog.exec()
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

You have to get the QComboBox and change the index so that 100% zoom is selected:

```py
dialog = QPrintPreviewDialog(self.printer)

combobox = dialog.findChild(QComboBox)
index = combobox.findText("100%")
combobox.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

Comment: It has helped me, I cannot vote for you, because I am a new member!!! Thank You very match..

Comment: @الزعيم2084 If my answer helped you do not forget to mark as correct, if you do not know how to do it then check the [tour]